# Error when running networkx on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, networkx

Today without doing anything this error appeared to me and to my friend at a university. Everything was working normally. I'm using Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook.

I ran python on Terminal and the error didn't appear.

I didn't change Anaconda directory.

Networkx is installed.

this is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f59024e867bc> in <module>()
----> 1 import networkx as nx
      2 import networkx as net
      3 
      4 import pandas as pd
      5 

~/Desktop/xxxxxxx/networkx.py in <module>()
     13 import matplotlib.pyplot
     14 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---> 15 from networkx.drawing.layout import shell_layout,circular_layout,spectral_layout,spring_layout,random_layout
     16 
     17 import random

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx.drawing'; 'networkx' is not a package
```

Did some networkx got deleted or infected or what?

Comment: is networkx installed?

Comment: yes, this is why it's bizarre

Comment: when you start the Jupyter Notebook you can select the version of python ? have you tried to see if you have multiple versions ?

Comment: I have Python 2 and 3, both of them work fine.

Comment: Can you type `import sys` and `sys.executable` and let me what you get ?

Comment: import sys works fine. sys.executable gives (/Documents/anaconda3/bin/python')

Comment: what version of networkx?  Was it recently updated?

Comment: I upgraded networkx using `pip install --upgrade networkx` and it didn't work.

Comment: If you type the same commands in the terminal, do you get the same path ? (/Documents/anaconda3/bin/python')

Comment: yes, I get the path as `~/Documents/anaconda3/bin/python`
Now I figured out something, If I created ipynb file in my desktop `import networkx` works fine, but  If I created ipynb file  in my project folder it gives the same error in the top.